# Referring to types in an external module in a definition

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm writing a library which will be exposed as an external module (Foo for this post).   I'm also writing jQuery plugins/extensions which will pull instances of objects (ex Foo.Button).

Something I've found which kind of worked, was to re-declare my classes as interfaces in my interface file:

```
declare interface JQuery_Button {
        text():string;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    fooButton(): JQuery_Button[];
}


interface JQuery {
    fooButton(): JQuery_Button[];
}
```

It works kind of, but leads to a lot of redundant code.  Also code which refers to my external module will be expecting a Foo.Button rather than a JQuery_Button.

I also had a look at declaring modules within the definition files, and I also got something which kind of worked.  However it required changing my jQuery.d.ts file to work, and I'd rather not change jQuery.d.ts.

In my ideal world, I'd like to be able to write code like this:

```
import Foo = require('Foo');
import $ = require('jquery');

let someButton : Foo.Button = $('#someButton').fooButton();
let buttonText : string = someButton.text();
```

Which is all nicely type checked and works with intellisense in VS Code.

Is there any way to do this or something like it?

Comment: Shouldn't the declaration files generated by tsc take care of all that? when run with the -declaration flag.

Answer (score 1):

> In my ideal world, I'd like to be able to write code like this:

If all you want is:

```
import Foo = require('Foo');
import $ = require('jquery');

let someButton : Foo.Button = $('#someButton').fooButton();
let buttonText : string = someButton.text(
```

Then the *only* interface you should be touching is `JQuery` (not `JQueryStatic`).

```
declare interface JQuery_Button {
        text():string;
}

interface JQuery {
    fooButton(): JQuery_Button[];
}
```